# Conditional row deleting based on value of another table

Tags: postgresql, join, conditional-statements, sql-delete

I am a novice with PostgreSQL and I have a problem with conditional delete.

I have a Pivot table:: TableA -> Spec_id-Status_id

I have another Pivot table:: TableB -> Spec_id-Trend_id

I need to delete the rows on TableB on the base of the following condition:

If, in TableB, the Spec_id (which had Status_id == 1 in TableA) has Trend_id == 4, the row Spec_id-Trend_id must be erased.

I know it's something like:

```
DELETE from TableB USING TableA WHERE TableA.Status_id == 1
```

But I don't know how to reference the Spec_id related to that choice.

Comment: please post DDL of relations - the tbale a,B definiton is not clear

Comment: Those are two different pivot tables. In TableA SpecId is related to the Status_id, in TableB SpecId is related to Trend_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join both tables:

```
DELETE FROM TableB
USING TableA
WHERE TableA.Spec_id = TableB.Spec_id
AND TableA.Status_id = 1;
```

Comment: thnk you. It was correct. I had to insert only the last part: AND TableB.Trend_id = 4;

Comment: I misread your question (thought deletion as based on `TableA.Status_id = 4`, if you want to delete rows where `Trend_id = 4`, you don't even need to use  `TableA`.
Simply use `DELETE FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Trend_id = 4;`